# When a spell specifies two possible resistances, how is one chosen?

Tags: spells, anima-beyond-fantasy, spell-resistance

When a spell specifies two possible resistances, how is one chosen?

For instance, the spell Create Memories specifies:

> Resisting the spell requires beating a MR or PsR check with a
>   Difficulty of 100.

Who determines which check is made, and how do they determine it?

Comment: Please use quote blocks, not code blocks, to quote text.  [There's a meta on that regarding screen readers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3057/22566).

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  I wasn't aware.

Comment: No worries.  I had to learn as well.  Glad to get the word out.

Comment: Would be nice if we had an inline quote.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find anywhere it is explicitly stated. However, the idea behind giving someone a choice of resistances implies that the highest one is relevant.
It is the spell's target's choice, whichever they want. They are not told if the save is different though.

The reason why it works this way, is because people's resistances may differ *a lot* from their other resistances, and represent different ways that people can overcome the magic of the spell... Either through force of will, or their soul itself, or maybe through raw physical power.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: The alternative simply doesn't make sense. At every point, the defender always has the advantage. It would be counter-intuitive for the caster to choose, as it would then be catering to the attacker. To give an example straight out of the book; There are quite a few psionics abilities that say "MR or PsR". In literal terms thats very inclusive. The spell is BOTH. Again. The book does not mention this anywhere explicitly, because it is fairly obvious how it is intended to be handled.

A similar counterpoint to this, do I get to choose whether you dodge or block?